# Ошибка при npm start Unexpected token <

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, redux

Пробовал переустановить все модули и убирать Provider, npm всё так же ругается на <. Может ли это как-то быть связано с babel?

ERROR in ./index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/tratata/index.js: Unexpected token (12:1)

```
  10 |
  11 | render(
> 12 |  <Provider store = {store}>
     |  ^
  13 |          <App />
  14 |  </Provider>,
  15 |  document.getElementById('root')
```

Comment: Вам нужно настроить компиляцию (транспиляцию). JSX это синтаксический сахар и его нужно компилировать в нормальный JS.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет) нужно было просто добавить пару библиотек babel-preset-env и babel-preset-es2015 и не забыть их указать в webpack.config